# Ruby On Rails Sign Up Login In Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got an error that param is missing or the value is empty: signUp

Here is my sign_up_controller.rb file:

```
class SignUpController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end
  
  def create
    signUp = signUp.new(signUp_params)
    if signUp.save
      session[:SignUp_id]= signUp.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:register_errors] = user.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

  private
    def signUp_params
        params.require(:signUp).permit(:email, :username, :password)
    end
end
```

And this is a sign up form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sign_up.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="/sign_up" method = "POST" style="padding: 100px">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>

  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%=form_authenticity_token%>">
  <label for="email"><b><p style="text-align:center">Email</p></b></label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

  <label for="username"><b><p style="text-align:center">Username</p></b></label>
  <input type="name" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

  <label for="password"><b><p style="text-align:center">Password</p></b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
  
  <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="submit" id="signupbutton" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <p style = "text-align: center; color: white" href="login"><%= link_to 'Already have an account? Log in', login_url %></p>
</div>
</form>

  <!--
    JS example. You don't need JS for this task's week for now.
  -->
  <%# <%= javascript_pack_tag 'home_example' %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm totally new with Ruby On Rails. I'm working on a signup/login page. Can someone help me to figure out what's wrong with my code, please?

Comment: Just a hint `sign_up_params` or `signup_params` is the ruby way of naming methods, using snake_case

Answer (score 1):

The way your form is currently built, the params are not going to be nested under `:signUp`. The fields will instead be at the top level of the params hash. You can do a `puts params` at the beginning of your `create` action to verify this.

Updating your `signUp_params` method should resolve this:

```
def signUp_params
  params.permit(:email, :username, :password)
end
```

If you really want the nested params, check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions.